# php 8 в OpenServer

Tags: windows-7, openserver, php8

Хочу установить PHP 8 в OpenServer. Скопировала пхп 8 в папку OpenServer/modules, выставила пхп 8 в настройках OpenServer, запустила сервер, и ... ничего не произошло. запустила локальный сайт - пишет 504 ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста, как установить 8-ю версию пхп в OpenServer

Comment: а проблема точно не в сайте?

Comment: создайте index.php в нем phpinfo(), ошибка таже?

Comment: Да. ошибка не прошла.

Comment: нет. ошибка не в сайте. 500 ошибки это ошибки на стороне сервера